# Java - in jar file, variable type changed from String to int and getting error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, executable-jar

New to gradle, I have a method where codes are being changed in the jar file expecting String but getting negative numbers which throwing the exceptions. Why are the codes changing? What can be done to correct it? Please see the original code before converted to executable jar and code in the jar while executing. Any help will be appreciated.
Original code:

```
Browser(String browserType) {
    Log.info("Creating an instance of a "+browserType+" browser");
    switch (browserType) {
        case Global.CHROME:
            if (Global.REMOTE_EXECUTION){
                ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
                this.setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
            }
            break;
        case Global.INTERNET_EXPLORER:
            InternetExplorerDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
            this.setDriver(new InternetExplorerDriver());
            break;
        default :
            Log.info("Browser type not supported: "+browserType);
            break;
    }
}
```

Code in the jar:

```
Browser(String browserType) {
    Log.info("Creating an instance of a " + browserType + " browser");
    byte var3 = -1;
    switch(browserType.hashCode()) {
    case -1361128838:
        if (browserType.equals("chrome")) {
            var3 = 0;
        }
        break;
    case 397430400:
        if (browserType.equals("internetexplorer")) {
            var3 = 1;
        }
    }

    switch(var3) {
    case 0:
        if (!Global.REMOTE_EXECUTION) {
            ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
            this.setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        InternetExplorerDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        this.setDriver(new InternetExplorerDriver());
        break;
    default:
        Log.info("Browser type not supported: " + browserType);
    }

}
```

Comment: I really don't understend what you are trying to do here.. Can you explaine your poruse?

Comment: Why are you switching based on the hash code instead of on the string values themselves?

Comment: @phflack I suppose the second example is  from some decompiler, and thats perhaps the way java implements `switch` on string constants.

Comment: Where do you get an exception? It looks like both code behave exactly the same.

Comment: Just to clarify - first example is the original code. after decompiling by java in the jar file

Comment: Second example is what I see in the jar after java decomplies. The compiler always converts a switch with a String into bytecode that does a switch on the int value of the hashCode() of the String. Decompiled bytecode almost always has noticeable differences from the original source. But I need to pass browserType as String -- exp. "chrome" on runtime. I am getting NumberFormatingException due to I am passing String browserType as chrome but in the switch statement, it is looking for a int value. What can I do to resolve this? Thanks.